# I made My own datastrcuture ArrayLinearList and I can't serialize it

Tags: java, serialization, data-structures, arraylist, save

I made a class `ArrayLinearList<T>` that is similar To `ArrayList`, but I cant implements `Serializable` in it, so I made other `class MyArray<T> extends ArrayLinearList<T> implements Serializable`, but when I try to save and read, my program reads an Array without elements

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import unal.datastructures.*;

public class MyArray <T>  extends ArrayLinearList<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4835247906545846769L; 
}
```

I'm try to save and load with this methods

```
public static void writeObject(Object o, String file){
    try{
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        oos.writeObject(o);
        oos.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Object readObject(String file){
    Object ans = null;
    try{
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        ans = ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }catch(IOException  | ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ans;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyArray<Integer> a = new MyArray<Integer>();
    for(int i=0 ; i<100 ; i++)
        a.add(i, i);
    System.out.println(a);
    writeObject(a,"Hola.dat");
    System.out.println("Readed array"+readObject("Hola.dat"));
}
```

and it's the output

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]

Readed array[]

Comment: Have you tried casting the result of `readObject()` back to `MyArray <T>`? Right now you're returning a plain object which probably doesn't have the same `toString()` overload as your `MyArray<T>` class.

Comment: I tried in super class ArrayLinearList Implementing Serializable, and it works perfect, so, the fields that belongs to super class, when it isn't Serializable, seem that its not serialize